# Sending back inner html table contents to Spring Model / Controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Java and Spring MVC, request your help on the below. We have a HTML table generated by jquery, the table values gets populated through the Model / Controller and has dropdown selections (they are part of the jsp form). The jquery helps me to add the values to the table based on user selections from the dropdown in the jsp page. So, I have the ability to add multiple user selected values (say name and email which are part of dropdown selections) and add it to the html table through jquery (a button helps me to add it). Now, my question is how to pass on these values (on the html table that the user selected) to the model / controller in Spring MVC, is there are way to bind these html values that are created as part of inner html by the jquery code. Is there a better way to achieve the user selections and send it back to the model / controller.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var subName = $("#selName").val();
            var editEmail = $("#selEmail").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td bgcolor=#f4f8fb class=medium><input type='checkbox' checked name='record'></td><td bgcolor=#f4f8fb class=medium>" + subName + "</td><td bgcolor=#f4f8fb class=medium >" + subEmail + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);

        });
        
        // Find and remove selected table rows
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
```